# Unable to reconfigure aurelia validation rules

Tags: single-page-application, aurelia

I am using [aurelia validation](https://github.com/aurelia/validation) V4 in my SPA.

I am trying to re-configure the `aurelia validation rules` depending on an option selected in a `dropdown`.

> I could not accomplish this because, each time newly added rules are
>   appending to the existing set of rules.

What I am trying to do is, remove existing rules for a property and assign new rules.

**how to re-configure Aurelia validation rules ?**

Answer (score 1):

the returned ValidationGroup has a `destroy()` function on it:

```
this.validate = this.validation.on(this)
                  .ensure('blah')
                  .isNotEmpty();

this.validate.destroy();
```

That should detach the observers to the values, meaning that any old rules will no longer be enforced.  I couldn't see whether this actually frees the memory associated with the ValidationGroup, so you might want to watch out for that. (though it still might)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have used the **destroy()** method on **this.validate** object. Also tried by using the **destroy()** method on each of the validation properties, which is in the **this.validate** object. Still the old validation rules exists in the validation object.

Comment: I've just come across a similar situation in my own code.  The only way I found to get around it, was to do this:
`this.validation.clear();   
 this.validation = null;
this._initializeValidation();`

with the `_initalizeValidation()` method containing the whole this.validation = this.aureliaValidation.on(this).ensure('blah')....